# D3 Treemap multiple parameter summing up the stack

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

This is actually a strange question. I am working on this https://secure.polisci.ohio-state.edu/faq/d3/zoomabletreemap_code.php and currently trying to pass more than one parameter in the treemap and trying to sum them up the stack, as whats mostly done in zoomable treemap.

The code documented for this change is given as:

```
// Aggregate the values for internal nodes. This is normally done by the
// treemap layout, but not here because of our custom implementation.
function accumulate(d) {
return d.children
? d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
: d.value;
}
```

But in my approach I have to sum up using more than one parameter, say value and count.
I tried to change the same code to add two parameters, but that didnt seem to do the trick, could someone guide me please:

```
   function accumulate(d) {
    return d.children
    ? d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
    : d.value;
    }
        function accumulate1(d) {
    return d.children
    ? d.count = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
    : d.count;
    }
```

As two separate function, and then calling them separately to sum both count and value up the stack, starting from leaf nodes.
But this is not working. Could you please guide me?

Comment: Well, this is probably too late for neoeahit (and besides, Lars's answer seemed to do the trick for the specific case), but the main reason the two different functions wouldn't have been working is because the second function still calls `accumulate(v)` when instead it should call `accumulate1(v)` in order to recurse properly.  With that change, each node would be given two different accumulated properties, one for value and one for count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to sum both values in the `accumulate` function:

```
function accumulate(d) {
  return d.children
    ? d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
    : d.value + d.count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I really appreciate it!
I am not able to get you on the second part here, what do you mean by use .sum?

Comment: The code stores the sum of `.value` and `.count` in a new attribute `.sum`. This is what you'll have to use when making the treemap.

Comment: Ok, I get you on this. But I had the misconception that the aggregation was based on value, and summed up all. I am sorry I am a newbie, and trying to learn.
Considering this example: https://secure.polisci.ohio-state.edu/faq/d3/zoomabletreemap_code.php where do you this this new change is implemneted. 


I think you mean[ I might be wrong] that drawing the treemap based on 

 .sort(function(a, b) { return a.sum - b.sum; })


Actually I want to draw it on the basis of "count" and color the nodes on basis of "value", hence i just want to draw it on basis of one domain

Comment: Ah, I think I know what you're getting at now. So you would sort on `count` and color on `value` like you've said. You don't need the separate attribute in your case, so I'll modify the answer to store the accumulation results in `.value`.

Comment: But the "value" is always on leaf nodes, in the edit you just made, how is it stacked up so as to color the parent node as well. I mean to say, The parent node should have this attribute "value", which defines its color?

Comment: That's exactly what the `accumulate` function does -- it assigns the sum of the children as the `.value` attribute of the parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped! I cant give you points( not allowed since I dont have enough points ) , but I will add some code to help the community :)

Comment: Actually, I just faced some issue. 
This is not stacking up both the count and value for me?
I am currently using :

function accumulate(d) {
  return d.children
    ? d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
    : d.value + d.count;
}

And then drawing according to:

var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
    .children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d.children; })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; })
    .ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))
    .sticky(false)
    .round(false);

This is not stacking up the count for me

Comment: You're using the value only for sorting and not to determine the size.

Comment: Accumulate: accumulates the nodes from the child!
layout: fixes the end points?

To draw we use rect?

 function rect(rect) {
    rect.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.dy) - y(d.y); });
  }

Please correct me where I am wrong. I dont see where should is the draw function is being called. or how does it gets the value from .value/.count?Now i feel confused! -- *feeling sorry*

Comment: You need to set the `.value` function. See for example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582).

Comment: OMG! .value(function(d) { return d.value; }) was the change?
Also, by default it takes .value, i wasnt able to find in mike treemap implementation anywhere where he had set the .value?

Comment: Also I am doing a mouseover on :

    g.selectAll(".child")
        .data(function(d) { return d.children || [d]})
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "child")
       
        .on("mouseover", function(d){

Console.log(d.value)} ...


but i am not getting any aggregated count, only the same count is being shown? BTW YOU ARE AWESUM!

Comment: Without the complete code of what you're trying to do I can really only guess.